# Rodando ajax dentro de uma tabela

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Boa tarde a todos, estou tentando fazer um código onde ele mostra a quanto tempo uma requisição foi aberta e eu tenho um ajax que fica atualizando esse contador a cada segundo, o meu problema é que essa requisição vem em uma tabela em que podem haver várias requisições, mas como o ajax só está rodando após a página carregar ele pega a data de base apenas da ultima requisição e replica em todas.

Javascript do ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      // Requisicao AJAX
      var requisicao = function() {
        var data_abertura = "<?php echo $data_base; ?>";
        $.ajax({
          url: "contador.php",

          type: "post",
          data: {
            data_abertura: data_abertura
          },
        }).done(function(resultado) {
          // Exibe o resultado no elemento com ID contador
          $(".contador").html(resultado);
        });
      };

      // Executa a requisicao com intervalo de 100ms
      setInterval(requisicao, 100);

    });
```

Javascript do contador.php :

```
$date = $_POST['data_abertura'];
echo $date;
$date = new DateTime($date);
$interval = $date->diff( new DateTime( ) );
echo $interval->format( '%a Dia %H Horas %i Minutos e %s Segundos' );
```

Trecho html onde trago o contador(com a tabela), não sei se ajuda:

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th id="CV" width="10%">Chamado</th>
                                    <th id="CV" width="10%">Problema</th>
                                    <th id="CV">Nome <br> Contato</th>
                                    <th id="CV">Departamento <br> Descrição</th>
                                    <th id="CV">Prioridade</th>
                                    <th id="CV">Data</th>
                                    <th id="CV" width="0%">Status</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                  <?php
                                  $query_2 =  "
                                      SELECT tb_ocorrencias.data_final, tb_ocorrencias.data_inicial, tb_ocorrencias.data_saida, tb_ocorrencias.id_prioridade,tb_ocorrencias.data_abertura,tb_ocorrencias.data_atendimento,  tb_ocorrencias.data_fechamento, tb_ocorrencias.id_ocorrencia, tb_problemas.problema, tb_usuarios.usuario, tb_usuarios.contato, tb_departamentos.departamento, tb_ocorrencias.descricao_ocorrencia, tb_status.status,tb_prioridades.prioridade, tb_ocorrencias.data_entrada
                                      FROM tb_ocorrencias
                                      INNER JOIN tb_usuarios on tb_usuarios.id_usuario = tb_ocorrencias.id_usuario
                                      INNER JOIN tb_problemas on tb_problemas.id_problema = tb_ocorrencias.id_problema
                                      INNER JOIN tb_departamentos on tb_usuarios.id_departamento = tb_departamentos.id_departamento
                                      INNER JOIN tb_prioridades on tb_prioridades.id_prioridade = tb_ocorrencias.id_prioridade
                                      INNER JOIN tb_status on  tb_status.id_status = tb_ocorrencias.id_status
                                      WHERE tb_ocorrencias.id_atendente = 0
                                      AND (tb_ocorrencias.id_departamento = '$id_departamento'
                                                      OR tb_ocorrencias.id_departamento = 184)
                                      ORDER BY tb_prioridades.prioridade DESC, tb_ocorrencias.id_ocorrencia ASC
                                  ";

                                  $resultado_2 = mysql_query($query_2, $conexao);
                                  while ($dados_2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_2)) {
                                    $data_base = $dados_2['data_abertura'];

                                    $id_ocorrencia =  $dados_2['id_ocorrencia'];
                                    $a = "<a href = 'chamados/atendente.php?numero=$id_ocorrencia' title = 'Visualizar' style = 'color: #000;'> $id_ocorrencia </a>";
                                      $data_abertura_1 = substr($dados_2['data_abertura'], 0, 10);
                                      $data_abertura = substr($data_abertura_1, -2, 2) . '/' . substr($data_abertura_1, -5, 2) . '/' . substr($data_abertura_1, 0, 4);
                                  ?>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td id="CC"> <?php echo "$a"; ?> </td>
                                        <td id="CV"> <?php echo $dados_2['problema']; ?> </td>
                                        <td id="CV"> <b> <?php echo $dados_2['usuario']; ?> </b> <br> <?php echo $dados_2['contato']; ?> </td>
                                        <td id="CV"> <b> <?php echo $dados_2['departamento']; ?> </b> <br> <?php echo $dados_2['descricao_ocorrencia']; ?> </td>
                                        <td id="CV"> <?php echo $dados_2['prioridade']; ?> </td>
                                        <td id="CC"> <?php echo $data_abertura; ?><p><span id="contador" class="contador" ></span> </p> </td>
                     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Que sentido faz pra vc repetir os mesmos id's em vários elementos? Vc sabe diferenciar `id` de `class`?

Comment: Boa noite, entendo que naqueles casos o correto é id unico, mas para o objetivo final isso não influencia, correto ?

Comment: O correto é observar as normas, onde diz que não se deve repetir o mesmo id na mesma página. Outra coisa é que você está usando um setInterval de um décimo de segundo chamando um AJAX. Isso é horrível porque pode não apenas congestionar o servidor como travar o navegador. E outra, isso `$(".contador").html(resultado);` irá alterar o HTML de todos os elementos que tiverem a classe `.contador` ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Ola amigo, sua query tem vários JOINS e isso faz com que existam múltiplos retornos por registro encontrado, o que vc precisa fazer é reagrupar os dados de retorno de forma correta. Alguns GROUP BY podem ajudar, mas eu reagruparia os dados direto no PHP em usando foreach. Aproveita e tira a query da view hehe, crie uma classe (DAO) pra controlar as requisições ao DB. Mais uma coisa, se vc quiser fazer esses AJAX em sequencia, melhor usar callbacks ou promisses para que a proxima requisição seja feita somente quando a requisição anterior tiver terminado :) Abraço.

Comment: Essa variável `$data_base`, você a utiliza em algum outro lugar que não seja a requisição Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde gente, consegui resolver o problema, fiz a requisição AJAX da tabela toda a cada um minuto, isso resolveu o problema, muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: boooa.. comigo deu certo tbm

Comment: Não precisava disso. Quando perguntei, e não obtive resposta, sobre a variável `$data_base` era para saber se era possível transformar essa variável num array contento todos os dados necessários para a atualização ou então criar um novo array com os dados da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

sua query tem vários JOINS e isso faz com que existam múltiplos retornos por registro encontrado, o que vc precisa fazer é reagrupar os dados de retorno de forma correta. Alguns GROUP BY podem ajudar, mas eu reagruparia os dados direto no PHP em usando foreach. Aproveita e tira a query da view hehe, crie uma classe (DAO) pra controlar as requisições ao DB. Mais uma coisa, se vc quiser fazer esses AJAX em sequencia, melhor usar callbacks ou promisses para que a próxima requisição seja feita somente quando a requisição anterior tiver terminado :) Abraço.